# What would be correct way to say “very fortunate “

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, adjective

Trying to find the correct adjective for “very lucky/very fortunate “ in feminine singular. Valde fortunata or ipsum fortunata?

Answer (score 2):

Think simple!

> Fortunatissima

… is the easiest answer. *Valde fortunata* is also correct, and *maxime fortunata* as well.

Comment: I think "Beatus -a -um" also works very appropriately -- "Beatissima" perhaps.

Comment: @Nickimite I recommend giving that as a separate answer, describing the meaning of the two adjectives (or at least *beatus*). I have an upvote waiting with your name on it. (+1 also to this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

A wall inscription from Pompeii: "phoenix felix et tu" = "The phoenix is fortunate/ happy and you (too).". Alternatively, "Be as fortunate/ happy as the phoenix.".

In Latin the phrase "et tu" has fold-back quality: "and you too". In contemporary English a response to a greeting could be: "And you (too).".

See: https://www.wondersandmarvels.com/2014/03/up-yours-brutus.html